# Can F-Spot be installed by a non-Admin user on a multi-user LineageOS phone?

Tags: lineageos, multi-user

I'm running LineageOS. F-Spot works fine for my main primary user which is an administrator (the default).

However, I can't get F-Spot to install on secondary users.

It fails and says, only "App not installed."

Comment: As I understand the app is already available to the secondary user but the [app data](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multiuser) is not shared. It's the secondary user not able to see the app in your case?

Comment: No, the secondary user can not see F-Spot in their app list. They don't see any of the installed Apps. The one exception is the play store.